# Halo 4 armor unlocks commendation

Tags: halo-4

In Halo 4, I've notice in the armor customization after I got the novice commendation that now it shows an armor piece that can be mastered. Is it mastered to the maxumun rank of the commendation (like 5/7) or it's for each?

How many assists do you need to get to master the Sunspot?

Comment: Almost positive you need the max rank, so 7/7 or 5/5, but I can't confirm for sure so I won't post as an answer.  My roommate is going for the armor you get for assassinations and you definitely need 5/5 for that (he's real close).

Comment: This is two different questions. The question about the number of assists for Sunspot visor should be a separate question from the one about the required rank for armor unlocks.

Comment: this question have two questions, but they are kind related, so I changed it a little to try make it fit and be more clean.

Answer (score 4):

It's the maximum. Even with the specializations, you have to reach the rank of 10 before you get the armor ability (armor equipment gets awarded at different levels).

I will check my Strategy Guide when I get home and update this answer on how many total assists is needed.

EDIT: Okay, big book of Halo 4 knowledge says

- 25 assists for level 1, worth 250 XP
- 50 assists for level 2, worth 500 XP
- 250 assists for level 3, worth 750 XP
- 500 assists for level 4, worth 1000 XP
- 1000 assists for level 5, worth 2500 XP and grants you the sunspot visor.

Get playing War Games.

Answer (score 1):

To unlock an armour piece, e.g like my Venator or Ranger armour, you need to complete the commendation to its maximum level.
Also here's a tip to get Ranger (combat opportunity) the way I did it was mainly going into battle, just before i died stick a grenade to an enemy and hit re-spawn now, you should get a kill from the grave, a hail mary and if your lucky maybe a killjoy, revenge or even double kill or more. this only works on infinity slayer or any games that let you respawn instantly